# how do I install 'libbacktrace' in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: cmake, makefile, webkit, ubuntu-22.04, backtrace

I can't find instructions to use [this](https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace)

I want to compile [WebKit](https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit) and there I get this error

```
-- Could NOT find LibBacktrace (missing: LIBBACKTRACE_INCLUDE_DIR LIBBACKTRACE_LIBRARY) 
CMake Error at Source/cmake/OptionsGTK.cmake:425 (message):
  libbacktrace is required for USE_LIBBACKTRACE
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  Source/cmake/WebKitCommon.cmake:237 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:21 (include)
```

so I have confirmed that they are using `ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace` package only

but here in I can't find any instructions to use it, can anyone please help.

please give commands for make, cmake, ninja, etc.

i can see there are some make something files there, so make script might be used. But i am not that an expert in these, if anyone could help.

Comment: Presence of `Makefile.am` suggests that the project uses Autotools for build. For its usage see e.g. [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2107577/3440745).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the solution

for anyone who comes and face this later on follow this

```
git clone https://github.com/ianlancetaylor/libbacktrace.git
cd libbacktrace 
mkdir build 
cd build 
../configure 
sudo make 
sudo make install
```

Comment: sorry my bad, have fixed it now. @TedLyngmo

Comment: That works fine. You probably don't need `sudo` for the first `make` though, only for `make install` in case you want to install it somewhere that requires special access privs.